# How to test significance of two added time series regression coefficients?

Tags: r, indicator

I have estimated a times series model including multiplicative indicator variables in R. The model looks like so:

```
 dynlm(returns.ts[,1] ~ 1 + Dummy.ts + Mkt.Rf + Mkt.Rf:Dummy.ts + SMB + SMB:Dummy.ts + HML + HML:Dummy.ts + RMW + RMW:Dummy.ts + CMA + CMA:Dummy.ts)
```

Dummy.ts is a coefficient indicating bull or bear periods on the stock market coded as 0 during bull markets and 1 during bear markets. If I have understood correctly the intercept by it self is the bull intercept and the intercept + Dummy.ts is the bear intercept.

Now I would like to test if the intercept plus the Dummy.ts indicator variable is significant. I do not want to perform a F-test or LR test, only add the coefficients together in order to test if the intercept is significant in the bear period. Is this possible? How would this be performed in R? Is there a standardized way? Is it possible to use Newey West standard errors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about building a simpler nested model without the new 'Dummy.ts' variable and calling anova() on your two models?

```
mod0 <- (returns ~ 1 + Mkt.rf + ..., data = datf)
mod1 <- (returns ~ 1 + Dummy.ts + Mkt.rf + ..., data = datf)

anova(mod0, mod1)
```

The last column is will provide you a Pr(>Chisq) value that you can compared to your p-value threshold (~.05), to determine whether your new predicted is significant? Keep in mind the models have to be nested, meaning all of the predictors must be conserved except for the new one being tested.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there anyway that I can test the intercept and the Dummy.ts variable together? Right now I am getting the same result as when I do t-tests for Dummy.ts. Since the coefficients have changed in the bear period i need to test the new intercept coefficient by itself.

Comment: If you want to see if you new intercept coefficient is a significant predictor, just build another nested set with and without the intercept coefficient.

Comment: I don't think you want to test the significance of new predictor by itself, because in reality you are interested in whether or not the new predictor is worthy of inclusion to your existing model. If you really want to, start a nested build up from the first predictor (maybe make this your bull/bear) and layer on other predictors. Then anova(m0,m1,m2...). There are two functions in the built in 'stats' package: aic() and bic() that can help make this process more automated, but at the end of the day you will need to be able to explain why you include the predictors you did